# Storing a closure in a structure — cannot infer an appropriate lifetime

Tags: closures, rust

I'm trying to implement the [State](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State#Definition_of_the_State_Monad) monad in Rust (`State` is effectively a wrapper over a function which takes original state and returns modified state and some result). This is how one can implement `State` in Haskell (monad operations where renamed to `unit` and `bind` for sake of simplicity):

```hs
data State s u = State { run :: s -> (u, s) }

-- return
unit :: u -> State s u
unit u = State $ \s -> (u, s)

-- (>>=)
bind :: State s u -> (u -> State s a) -> State s a
bind m f = State $ \s ->
             let (u, s') = run m s
             in run (f u) s'
```

So I try to rewrite it in Rust:

```rust
pub struct State<'r, S, U> {
    priv run: 'r |S| -> (U, S)
}

pub fn unit<'r, S, U>(value: U) -> State<'r, S, U> {
    State {
        run: |state| (value, state)
    }
}
```

(Actually I'm not sure if the definition of the `run` field is legal — it's [said](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/10720#issuecomment-29622224) to be a bug).

This code doesn't compile:

```
/some/path/lib.rs:31:12: 31:36 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
/some/path/lib.rs:31         run: |state| (value, state)
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/some/path/lib.rs:29:52: 33:2 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the block at 29:51...
/some/path/lib.rs:29 pub fn unit<'r, S, U>(value: U) -> State<'r, S, U> {
/some/path/lib.rs:30     State {
/some/path/lib.rs:31         run: |state| (value, state)
/some/path/lib.rs:32     }
/some/path/lib.rs:33 }
/some/path/lib.rs:31:12: 31:36 note: ...so that closure does not outlive its stack frame
/some/path/lib.rs:31         run: |state| (value, state)
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/some/path/lib.rs:29:52: 33:2 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime &'r  as defined on the block at 29:51...
/some/path/lib.rs:29 pub fn unit<'r, S, U>(value: U) -> State<'r, S, U> {
/some/path/lib.rs:30     State {
/some/path/lib.rs:31         run: |state| (value, state)
/some/path/lib.rs:32     }
/some/path/lib.rs:33 }
/some/path/lib.rs:30:5: 30:10 note: ...so that types are compatible (expected `State<'r,S,U>` but found `State<,S,U>`)
/some/path/lib.rs:30     State {
                         ^~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Seems like I need to explicitly specify the lifetime for the closure expression when instantiating `State` in `unit`, but I just don't know how, so I need help here. Thanks.

---

**EDIT**: Unfortunately, I cannot use `proc`s (as Vladimir suggested), because a `State` can be executed arbitrary number of times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is completely legitimate. Currently it is completely impossible to return closures which can be called multiple times from functions (unless they were passed to these functions as arguments).

You can easily find out that you have made a mistake in lifetimes usage when you look for lifetime annotations position. When lifetime parameter is used only in arguments or only in return values, then there is a mistake in your code. This is exactly your case - `unit` has `'r` lifetime parameter, but it is used only in return value.

Your code fails to compile because you're creating *stack* closure and are trying to store it inside an object which will be returned to the caller. But the closure is created on the stack, and when you return from the function, that stack space is invalidated, i.e. your closure is destroyed. Borrow checker prevents this.

Currently there are only two kinds of closures in Rust - stack boxed closures and one-off heap boxed closures (procs). You could do what you want with a proc, but you will be able to call it only once. I'm not sure if this is OK for your needs, but here you go:

```rust
pub struct State<S, U> {
    priv run: proc(S) -> (U, S)
}

pub fn unit<S: Send, U: Send>(value: U) -> State<S, U> {
    State {
        run: proc(state) (value, state)
    }
}
```

I had to add `Send` kind because procs need their environment to be sendable.

In future, when (or if) dynamically sized types land, you will be able to create regular boxed closure which can be called multiple times and which own their environment. But DST are still in design and development.

Comment: Also, I did a little research on closure types. Since I'm new to Rust, I cannot be completely sure, but I believe one could achieve the desired behavior using managed closures, which were recently removed from the language.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Moreover, there were owned closures, which were removed too. Hopefully DST will bring them back.

Comment: FWIW, the Rust community doesn't call `||` an unboxed closure: `||` is equivalent to a `&Fn<...>` trait object (for a hypothetical `Fn` trait), i.e. it's been boxed into a trait object where the data (the closure environment in this case) lies on the stack. An "unboxed closure" is the `x` in `&x as &Fn<...>` which can't be created yet, but work is being done on it. (I think this work is more relevant than DST. [Start of the discussion](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2013-December/007594.html).)

Comment: @dbaupp, thanks, you're absolutely right. I'll fix the answer.